# hide an image in after a specific time period

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I hide an image after a specific time period?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest way I know is to use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

and then set a method:

```
-(void)hideImage{

 image.hidden = YES;

}
```

For the hiding method it is really depends on what kind of image you are using and if you want to show it again later.